# Django: Set is_active = True manually, no way?

Tags: python, django, django-registration, django-guardian

For a slew of reasons that detailing will make this post too long, I'm using a custom user model, alongside django-registration, and guardian.

Everything is working quite alright, but I'm trying to make it so every user registered is automatically set to active, so "they" (right now it's only me emulating users) can login instantly. The way I did so far is by manually setting that field to "1" (True) in the SQL table.

It seems that no matter how I arrange things, the `is_active` flag is always `False` until I change it manually in SQL, even though I'm printing it to my console and it's showing True when I register.

I *did* get it to work by changing `user.save()` to `user.save(commit=True)`, that does make the `is_active` flag `True` and allows the user to log-in, but it always throws an error that says:

> TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'

Of course, this is all for testing purposes and ***I do*** intend to introduce email verification, but I'm very intrigued on why I'm not able to simply set the flag and `save()`.

**Here's my `register/forms.py`:**

```
class GeneralUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    business_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GeneralUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1',
                  'password2', 'business_name']

    # TODO: only create all objects if no error is found
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(GeneralUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])

        # TODO: create permissions, including groups.
        if commit:
            user.is_active = True  # remove before deployment
            print(user.is_active)
            user.save() # LINE I CHANGED
            business = Business.objects.create(name=self.cleaned_data['business_name'], owner=user)
            business.save()
            mng_grp = create_perms_for_biz(business, user)
            user.groups.add(mng_grp)
        return user
```

**And my `register/models.py`:**

```
class GeneralUser(AbstractUser, GuardianUserMixin):

    username = models.CharField(
        ('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        error_messages={
            'unique': ("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(('email address'), blank=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        ('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )

    objects = UserManager()

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    business_name = models.CharField(('business name'), max_length=150, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'


    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)


def get_custom_anon_user(User):
    return User(
        username='AnonymousUser',
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing [ModelForm.save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method that do take a `commit` argument with the [Model.save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method that does not.